# What is the difference between "dailyLimitExceeded" and "quotaExceeded" in YouTube data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I run the program using the youtube data API, sometimes I get a dailyLimitExceeded error and a quotaExceeded error. In the case of dailyLimitExceeded, if I run it again after a few seconds, 
sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work. However, in the case of quotaExceeded, quota is not initialized until 5 o'clock of the next day in the Pacific. Only after the quota has been initialized can the program resume normal operation.

I understand quotaExceeded to some extent, but I don't know exactly what dailyLimitExceeded is.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the *latency* of the data refresh rate. if you sending a request to Youtube frequently. Youtube protects himself and gives us Daily Limit exceeded results temporarily, but a bit time later it will work properly with a new request.

Check out the report:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/150106191